# Need help with after Insert Trigger test class

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class

I have a trigger on Account that inserts into Property after insert and I am have trouble with the test class. I'm not sure how to handle it since I am new to Apex.

Here is the trigger.

```
trigger CreatePropertRecord on Account (after Insert) {

for(Account a : trigger.new)

if( a.Number_of_Properties__c > 0 )

    {

    Property__c v = new Property__c (); 

    if( a.Property_Name__c <> Null )
        v.Name = a.Property_Name__c;
    Else
        v.Name = a.Name;

    v.Property__c = a.id ;
    v.Property_Code__c = a.Property_ID__c ;
    v.Bathrooms_Number__c= a.Number_Bathrooms__c;
    v.Bedrooms_Number__c= a.Bedrooms_Number__c;
    v.Beach_Front__c = a.Beach_Front__c ;
    v.Street__c = a.Street__c;
    v.City__c = a.City__c;
    v.State_Province__c = a.State_Province__c;
    v.Zip_Postal_Code__c = a.Zip_Postal_Code__c;
    v.Country__c = a.Country__c;
    v.Ski_In_Ski_Out__c = a.Ski_In_Ski_Out__c ;
    v.Resort__c = a.Resort__c;
    v.Property_Type__c = a.Property_Type__c;
    v.Number_of_Properties__c = a.Number_of_Properties__c;
    v.Ownership_Status__c = a.Ownership_Status__c ;
    v.Property_Owner_Status__c = a.Property_Owner_Status__c;
    v.Expected_Annual_GLR__c = a.Expected_Annual_GLR__c;
    insert v ;
    }}
```

Here is the test class that was created that is not working.

```
@isTest 
private class CreatePropertRecordTest {
static testMethod void validateCreatePropertRecord() {
   account a = new account(
   a.Property_Name__c='test name',
   a.Property_ID__c='test id',
   a.Number_Bathrooms__c='1B',
   a.Bedrooms_Number__c='1B',
   a.Beach_Front__c=TRUE,
   a.Street__c='test street',
   a.City__c='test city',
   a.State_Province__c='test state',
   a.Zip_Postal_Code__c='test zip',
   a.Country__c='test country',
   a.Ski_In_Ski_Out__c=TRUE,
   a.Resort__c='test resort',
   a.Property_Type__c='Cabin',
   a.Number_of_Properties__c=1,
   a.Ownership_Status__c='Already own',
   a.Property_Owner_Status__c='LLC',
   a.Expected_Annual_GLR__c='50000'
   );

   // Insert account
   insert a;

   // Retrieve the new account
   a = [SELECT description FROM account WHERE Id =:a.Id];

   // Test that the trigger correctly updated the description
   System.assertEquals(null, a.description);
}}
```

Comment: Your trigger doesn't seem to be updating the description. What are you actually having trouble with? You have many of the right ideas - what it seems like you should be doing is querying for the Property records and asserting it's values.

Comment: Are you not including the account name in the method to create it? That would cause the account insert to fail.

Comment: @Stephen, the trouble I am having is a lack of Apex experience. :) This test class was handed to me from someone else and I am trying to learn as I go. I assumed I need to assert the values created in Property once the trigger has fired. I'm not sure how to do that. I understand the need for test classes, etc, but I'm not sure how to build it for this trigger. In the test class, do I have to insert a record into account forcing the trigger to fire then select from Property looking for the new records?

Comment: @Mays Yes, that is exactly correct. Since this is a trigger on inserting Accounts that will create a new Property - that is that you have to test. After you insert the Account, instead of querying the account again, query the Property__c table SELECT fields WHERE Property__c = a.id and Assert that the fields from the Property query are the same as the Account that you inserted.

Answer (score 2):

The problems with your test class are:

1. Account name is not passed to while creation of account
2. Assert might fail because when you compare with text it will blank(eg: '' or null)

Best practice to follow for DML/soql:

> Avoid SOQL Queries or DML statements inside FOR Loops

Here Dml statement can be reduced into 1.

```
List<Property__c> propertyList = new List<Property__c>();

for(Account acc :Trigger.new) {
    Property__c temp =new Property__c();
    //field mapping propery.field = account.field
    propertyList.add(temp);
}

//dml statement outside loop
insert propertyList;
```

Comment: I've edited your answer to use proper code & post formatting, as well as fixed a few spelling errors. See [Advanced Editing Help](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for more information on Markdown based formatting.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a test you need to ask yourself: '*What is the tested code suppose to do*'. In this case it looks like your trigger is creating a new Property__c record whenever you create an Account that has Number_of_Properties__c > 0.

So you should be testing four scenarios:

1. Inserting an Account with Number_of_Properties__c = 0
2. Inserting an Account with Number_of_Properties__c = 1 (or more)
3. Inserting an Account with Number_of_Properties__c = 1 (or more) with no Property_Name__c
4. Inserting an Account with Number_of_Properties__c = 1 (or more) with Property_Name__c

And in each scenario you should be asserting the functionality of the code.

When Number_of_Properties__c = 0 there should be no Property__c record.

When Number_of_Properties__c > 0 there should be a Property__c record that has it's fields set as per the code.

When Property_Name__c is set the Property Name should be the same.

When Property_Name__c is not set the Property Name should be the Account Name.

Others have pointed out other good observations - you are missing the Account.Name in the test. And your trigger itself is poorly optimized.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help, everyone, especially Stephen.